# Use non default route as non privileged user

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, sudo, route, interface

On Ubuntu 16.04, the default route for IPv4 is an interface other than eth0.

If I try to

```
curl -vvv --interface eth0 v4.ifconfig.co
```

I get

```
* SO_BINDTODEVICE eth0 failed with errno 1: Operation not permitted; will do regular bind
```

But if I `sudo` it works fine.

How do I change the config so that services running under this non privileged user can use eth0 for IPv4? I don't think I can just change sudo config to allow this because I don't want the service to run anything as root. I also want to maintain the default route for IPv4 on the current interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Per-process routing](http://blog.sebastien.raveau.name/2009/04/per-process-routing.html). Assuming the user is foo, the IP address of eth0 is 10.1.1.1, and the router is 10.1.1.254 :

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner foo -j MARK --set-mark 42
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -m mark --mark 42 -j SNAT --to-source 10.1.1.1
ip rule add fwmark 42 table 42
ip route add default via 10.1.1.254 dev eth0 table 42
```

You'll also need `sysctl net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter=0`.

Comment: I assume `--uid-owner foo` makes all processes from user foo use eth0?

Comment: Yes, all processes.

Comment: How would you compare this method with using network namespaces OR cgroups+iptables+policy routing, as described in http://www.evolware.org/?p=369 ?

Comment: Does this work for TCP and UDP?

Comment: Yes, it works with anything netfilter can handle.

Comment: Seems like the last two rules do not persist on reboot. how do i make them stick?

Comment: I'm following https://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/05/29/a-quick-introduction-to-linux-policy-routing/ and trying to figure out how to make it permanent.

Comment: rp_filter set to 2 should suffice (see https://serverfault.com/a/816421/34560). It works with 2, but I still can't get it to persist across reboots.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `getcap/setcap` and check out `man 7 capabilities`. In your case some `NET_CAP_*` should do the job.

Comment: The command is `sudo setcap cap_net_raw=eip /usr/bin/curl`